# Extracting residuals of lmer model - dealing missing values

Tags: r, lme4

I'm trying to extract the residuals from a model I have estimated using lmer() to store as a new variable. There were some missing values, so I'm trying to use subsetting to skip these rows in order to have the residuals end up at the correct point in the dataframe.

This is what I've done:

```
df$newvariable[!is.na(df$na)]<-resid(model)
```

Where model is was estimated using the lmer function.

The error I get is:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "newvariable", value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 3332

In addition: Warning message:

In is.na(df$na) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

I've tried some of the other things, including this:

```
df$newvariable<-resid(model,na.action=na.omit)
```

This at least produces data, but I know it's incomplete and so can't fit it:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "e.bi", value = c(6.75180624992464,  :      
replacement has 3083 rows, data has 3332
```

I'm very new to R clearly and not much idea of what I'm doing. For reference, I'm actually trying to copy an analysis done in this journal article http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fpsyg.2016.00891/full which includes the code - see p.5 for this particular part. I'm not sure why mine won't work! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: To meet the MCVE requirement for posting this in the R tag please include all data and code necessary to fully reproduce this error within the question itself. Having said that, I imagine you need to impute missing values before you train the model.

Comment: Try setting `na.action = na.exclude` in you `lmer()` function, and then extract the residuals using `resid`. The resulting length of the residuals should be equal  with an NA value for each observation that has missing data on one or more variables in your model (instead of omitting these observations as `na.omit` does).